# How can I install a library in an environment?

Tags: python, pycharm, environment

I'm currently using python 3.6.5. My assignment requires python 2. So I created an environment with python 2.7 in Pycharm. I want to install the numpy library. However, it cannot be installed by using Pycharm. Pycharm hints to install via terminal. My operating System is Win10 and the path of python 2.7 is

```
C:\Users\yashir\PycharmProjects\CSC411_A1\venv\Scripts\python.exe
```

I tried

```
pip2 install numpy
```

It returns

```
'pip2' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the following and it works.

```
C:\Users\yashi>cd PycharmProjects\CSC411_A1\venv\Scripts

pip2 install numpy
```

But it raised another problem

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement numpy (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for numpy
```

So I download the file numpy-1.15.2-cp27-none-win_amd64 and do

```
pip2 install numpy-1.15.2-cp27-none-win_amd64
```

Then it works.

Answer (score 0):

Before you can use pip in the terminal, you need to add it to the environment variables:

This page will guide you: [link](https://matthewhorne.me/how-to-install-python-and-pip-on-windows-10/)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using .whl files, use the following command instead:

python -m pip install numpy

Not 100% sure if this will work for python 2.7